# JPA: Using AttributeConverter in @Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I wrote my own AttributeConverter to encrypt and decrypt ByteArrays based on [thoughts-on-java](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/) and looks similar to:

```
@Converter
public class CryptoByteArrayConverter implements AttributeConverter < Byte[], Byte[] > {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(Byte[] attribute) {
        //...works fine
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Byte[] convertToEntityAttribute(Byte[] dbData) {
        //...works also fine
    }
}
```

My entity class is using this converter:

```
@Entity
public class ArchivedInvoice implements Serializable {
//...
    @Convert(converter=CryptoByteArrayConverter.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Byte[] encryptedXml;
//...
}
```

Everything works fine until here. The data I had set is encrypted in the database and is also decrypted after getting the result set.
But the CryptoByteArrayConverter is not used in @Query automatically. 
Is it possible to activate it or is there another good workaround?

For example:

```
@Query("SELECT ai FROM #{#entityName} ai WHERE (ai.encryptedXml = :xml)")
Page < ArchivedInvoice > findByXml(@Param("xml") byte[] xml, Pageable p);
```

Comment: what do you mean "is not used in the context of every query"?

Comment: The converter is ignored in the @Query.

Comment: What does that mean? Post your query, and post the SQL invoked and post the results

Comment: you expecting it to decrypt the encrypted value to do the comparison? How can it do that ? The converter runs in Java space, not in the DB

Comment: I expected something like that because the OR-mapper also decrypt the encrypted values of the result set. I really need it to realize a requirement.

Comment: Well it won't ... the query is run in the datastore!. The converter runs on data pushed into, and pulled from the DB. It doesn't run internal to a query. Only way you could do that is have a stored proc or function in the DB that does the encryption/decryption ... and a JPA AttributeConverter is not that

Answer (score 2):

I make it run and realized that it is not needed to check if the decrypted values are equal or not. A comparison of the encrypted value of the DB attribute and the encrypted parameter returns the correct results.
After changing the parameter type from byte[] to Byte[] the AttributeConverter has been activated automatically and encrypted the parameter (xml):

```
@Query("SELECT ai FROM #{#entityName} ai WHERE (ai.encryptedXml = :xml)")
Page < ArchivedInvoice > findByXml(@Param("xml") Byte[] xml, Pageable p);
```

The following test shows what I mean:

```
@Test
public void saveTestEncryption() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    repository.deleteAll();
    ArchivedInvoice arcInv = createDTO(0);
    repository.save(arcInv);
    assertEquals(1, repository.count());
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 25);
    //Not encrypted!
    String xml = arcInv.getXml();
    Page < ArchivedInvoice > list =
            repository.findByXml(ByteUtils.convert(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")), pageRequest);
    assertEquals(1, list.getTotalElements());
    xml += "A";
    list = repository.findByXml(ByteUtils.convert(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")), pageRequest);
    assertEquals(0, list.getTotalElements());
}
```